# How to get wpa2-psk key out of the wpa_supplicant daemon?

Tags: android, linux, wireless

I have an Android device using Wi-Fi Direct WPS-pbc method to connect to an other group owner (AP). My AP is using each session the same wpa2-psk key, negotiated by the WPS setup. I want to have that key to decrypt the traffic in Wireshark. The packets are sniffed with Kismet. Is there a way to get that key out of the wpa_supplicant daemon on Android? I have access to the Android device, but not to the AP.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in to the configuration file where wpa_supplicant stores each network connection. In Android it is generally /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: I tried that, but I didn't had access to that file. Rooting of the phone was also not an option. I avoiding the problem... But thanks for the remark.

Comment: You can try `P2P_GET_PASSPHRASE` command through wpa_cli. `wpa_cli -i/data/misc/wifi/sockets/p2p0 p2p_get_passphrase`